# hHow to connect ROS Hydro Medusa with Gazebo 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am beginner to ROS and gazebo and I have been  trying to connect my gazebo 3.0 to ROS Hydro, both of them have been installed on ubuntu 12.04. I tried to follow the instruction on the gazebo website, but it always says you have broken package or something similar to that. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174619/hhow-to-connect-ros-hydro-medusa-with-gazebo-3.0-on-ubuntu-12.04?/) by [KennyHimawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/18963/kennyhimawan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo 3.0 is much newer and is not tested against ROS Hydro. Gazebo 1.9 is tested against Hydro according to http://gazebosim.org/#status

if you want to make this happen you will need to compile most things from source and it will be a lot of work to get things to work. And as this is not a supported combination expect to do most of the work yourself.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KennyHimawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/18963/kennyhimawan/) on 2014-06-24**:
Okay, thanks for your answer, then it is better for me to change back to Gazebo 1.9. Cheers!